# return a constructible from a variant being constructed from an alternative

Tags: c++

Is it okay to have a struct that is constructible from a variant (say, from std::variant), and to return such structure implicitly constructed from one of the variant's alternatives?

Consider the following code:

```
#include <utility>

struct type1_t
{
};
struct type2_t
{
};

struct variant
{
    /*template <typename T>
    variant(T&& t)
    {}*/
    variant(type1_t){}
};

struct var_holder_t
{
    var_holder_t(variant v)
        : m_var(std::move(v))
    {}

private:
    variant m_var;
};

var_holder_t foo()
{
    return type1_t{ };  // <====== offending line
}
```

MSVC 2017, 2019 allow that, but GCC and clang does not compile. Changing to the other variant's constructor or even using boost::variant or std::variant doesn't help.

Worth noting that changing the offending line to `return {type1_t{ }};` makes it compile somehow. Currently I'm lost, though technically speaking adding two extra {} doesn't do much harm readability-wise, probably I'll stick to that at the moment, just wish for an answer.

Also making var_holder_t's constructor template (forwarding) helps, and it makes var_holder_t constructible from type1_t directly (and very likely a lot better performance-wise), but at the moment I want to keep var_holder_t completely non-template - it's supposed (thought, designed) to be casually-written simple code.

---

Update: what actually confused me is that Clang emits this message:

`note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'type1_t' to 'variant' for 1st argument var_holder_t(variant v)`

Which is weird, because clearly there is a conversion from `type1_t` to `variant`, but looks like its just bogus diagnostics. To put it together, I think I can come up with a simple reason why the construction above does not work: it requires two implicit conversions, but the rules are that only one is considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below statement works because [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization) is being performed.

```
return {type1_t{ }};
```

> **copy-list-initialization**
>
> ```
> return { arg1, arg2, ... } ;    (8)
> ```
>
> **List initialization is performed in the following situations:**
>   ...
>   direct-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered)
>   ...
>   8) in a return statement with braced-init-list used as the return expression and **list-initialization initializes the returned object**

Here `var_holder_t` is initialized with a `type1_t` object and it works as expected.